# What daemons should or can be disabled on a Linux VM, especially hardware related ones?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, service, linux

What daemons should or can be disabled on a Linux VM, especially hardware related ones? I want to develop VMs using KVM and transfer them to coLinux after I finish with them.

Are there some daemons that can or should be removed, especially those assuming that they are running on physical systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more info on OS and default installed packages. You can first start minimizing the daemons that start on boot by selecting no extra software packages when provisioning the OS.

Some common daemons you won't need (based on my experience with RHEL/CentOS):

bluetooth
avahi-daemon
cups
lvm2-monitor
mdmonitor
anacron
smartd
nscd
gpm
xfs
rpcidmapd
hidd
pcscd
atd